# How to visualize single column from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm new to data science & pandas.  I'm just trying to visualize the distribution of data from a single series (a single column), but the histogram that I'm generating is only a single column (see below where it's sorted descending).

My data is over 11 million rows. The max value is 27,235 and the min values are 1.  I'd like to see the "count" column grouped into different bins and a column/bar whose height is the total for each bin.  But, I'm only seeing a single bar and am not sure what to do.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count':[27235,26000,25877]})
```

Solution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df['count'].hist()
```

[image]

Alternatively

```
sns.distplot(df['count'])
```

Comment: I'm seeing this:  `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'`

Comment: I put in column as a wildcard. See my edits. I expected you would .column to your columname

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's close to what I originally had and it's still producing just the one bar.  I tried your lines and did get the same chart that you uploaded.  I'm wondering if I didn't import my data correctly.  

df.dtypes produces:
count    int64
dtype: object

Comment: If dtypes is the issue, do df['counts']=df['counts'].astype(int)

Comment: Hmmm, still the same, just one bar in the chart.  :(  Maybe 11 million is too many rows?

Comment: yeah, I took just the first 10 rows from my csv file and created a new dataframe.  That chart looked fine/expected.

Comment: Oh, now I'm thinking that there are simply *so* many rows whose 'count' is small that they're rows with higher values are tiny (and not visible).